# PHP - How to create a simple multi-language app using gettext() with .po file

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext, multilingual, poedit

My server installed: PHP Version `5.6.33-3+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1`
with enable `gettext` extension.

I am trying to build a very common simple multi-language app, I have googled a lot including SO but not found any working solution.

Here my steps:

**1.) Check gettext extension installed.**

**2.) Setup a demo project**

Directory Structure:

```
/demo
-- test.php 
-- /locale/
----/en_GB/
------/LC_MESSAGES/
-------- test.po
-------- test.mo
----/en_IN/
------/LC_MESSAGES/
-------- test.po
-------- test.mo
```

**3.) Check available local in my system**

```
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

**4.) Use two different language `en_GB` & `en_IN`**

**5.) Create application file `test.php`**

```
<?php

// select default locale
$locale = 'en_GB.utf8';   // or 'en_GB'

// set locale from url string
$locale = (isset($_GET['locale'])) ? $_GET['locale'] : $locale; 

// set lang env
putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale");

//set locale:
setlocale( LC_MESSAGES, $locale);

// my understanding for this, is name of my translation files for application ?
$domain = 'test';

// Sets the path for a domain
bindtextdomain($domain, dirname(__FILE__).'/locale'); // where translation files are

//or this:
//bindtextdomain("*", dirname(__FILE__).'/locale');

// Not sure i need to set codeset or not ?
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);
?>

<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body>

<?php

echo _("hello");

?>

</body>
</html>
```

**6.) Create translation file for `locale/en_GB/LC_MESSAGES/test.po`**

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2018-02-19 12:16+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2018-02-19 12:16+0530\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"Language: en_GB\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.7.1\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: test.php\n"

#: test.php:38
msgid "hello"
msgstr "Hello"
```

**7.) Create translation file for `locale/en_IN/LC_MESSAGES/test.po`**

```
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2018-02-19 12:16+0530\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: 2018-02-19 13:01+0530\n"
"Language-Team: \n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
"X-Generator: Poedit 1.8.7.1\n"
"X-Poedit-Basepath: ..\n"
"Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1);\n"
"Last-Translator: \n"
"Language: en_IN\n"
"X-Poedit-SearchPath-0: test.php\n"

#: test.php:38
msgid "hello"
msgstr "Namaste"
```

I have used poedit for compiling  .mo files

Q.1 ) Is there anything which I missed for best practice?

Updated: I have fixed gettext not working issue by putting `.utf8` after locale string and restart server & its remove my head pain ;)

here my `phpinfo(INFO_ENVIRONMENT)` results
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you forget to direct which domain you are going to use as default?

```
// Not sure i need to set codeset or not ?
bind_textdomain_codeset($domain, 'UTF-8');

textdomain($domain);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, sorry i forgot write textdomain() to post in question but still not working

Comment: MAgic: i just change putenv("LANGUAGE=$locale"); and its works

Answer (score 0):

my problem was that server cached the .mo files so when process for first time it works fine but when the mo files will be change those changes wasn't visible on app.
You could try this approx

```
<?php
namespace utils;
class simple_i18n
{
  const DIR_LANG   =  '/LC_MESSAGES/';
  const CODESET    =  'UTF-8';
  private static $domain     =   null;
  private static $locale     =   'en_US';

  public static function init( $locale, $domain )
  {
    self::$locale  =  $locale;
    self::$domain  =  $domain;
    self::preparePOMO( self::$domain, self::$locale, self::CODESET, I18N_DIR );
    self::activateLocaleSettings();
    self::generateNewTextdomain();
  }
  private static function activateLocaleSettings()
  {
    putenv( 'LC_ALL=' . self::$locale );
    setlocale( LC_ALL, self::$locale );
  }
  private static function generateNewTextdomain()
  {
    $textDomain  =  sprintf( '%s_%s', self::$domain, self::$locale );
    // Set base directory for all locales
    bindtextdomain( $textDomain, I18N_DIR );
    // Set domain codeset (optional)
    bind_textdomain_codeset( $textDomain, self::CODESET );
    // File: ./locale/de_DE/LC_MESSAGES/domain_de_DE.mo
    textdomain( $textDomain );
  }
  private static function preparePOMO( &$domain, $locale, $codeset, $directory )
  {
    if ( !is_dir( $directory . '/' . $locale . self::DIR_LANG ) ){
      self::$locale  =  'en_EN';
      return;
    }
    if ( !( $gestor  =  opendir( $directory . '/' . $locale . self::DIR_LANG  ) ) ) return;
    while( false !== ( $entrada = readdir( $gestor ) ) ) :
      preg_match( '/\d{14,25}/',$entrada, $matches );
      if ( $matches ) :
        unlink( $directory . '/' . $locale . self::DIR_LANG . $entrada );          
      endif;
    endwhile;    
    $auxDom  =  $domain;
    $domain  =  $domain . date( 'Ymdhisu' );
    copy( $directory . '/' . $locale . self::DIR_LANG . $auxDom . '_' . $locale . '.mo', $directory . '/' . $locale . self::DIR_LANG . $domain . '_' . $locale . '.mo'  );     
  }
}
```

This code create a copy for .mo file and prevent cached from server (otherwise you must restart server).
For usage:

```
include_once '[PATH TO simple_i18n.php file]/simple_i18n.php';
```

Now you must define directory for .po and .mo files:

```
defined( 'I18N_DIR' ) || define( 'I18N_DIR', '[PATH TO LOCALE]/locale' );
$locale     =  'en_GB'; //or 'en_IN'
$domain     =  'your_domain_name'; //in your case test but you must add 'en_GB' and 'en_IN' as sufix in every directory
\utils\simple_i18n::init( $locale, $domain );
```

And now you can use it!

```
<?php echo _( 'hello' );?>
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: each LC_MESSAGES directories must be writable of course

Comment: Technically, the server does not "cache" the MO file: it reads the file when starting up then keeps it in memory until the next restart. So when the MO file is updated, the server needs to be restarted so that it reads it again.